# Trying to switch character unity 2d

Tags: c#, character, unity-game-engine

I'm making a platformer where for different aspects of the level you have to change character. Each character is to have different properties and such. I wacthed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vD5pW97-050 but this is basically just changing the sprite as both characters are part of the same gameobject with the same rigidbody and collider. I am using c# and would really love some help if anyone knew a solution. Here's my player controllers script, which includes the character switch script found in the tutorial. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class controller : MonoBehaviour
{
public float topSpeed = 15f;
bool facingRight = true;

bool grounded = false;

public Transform groundCheck;

float groundRadius = 0.2f;
GameObject Player, Player2;
int characterselect;

public float jumpForce = 700f;

public LayerMask whatIsGround;
void Start()
{
    characterselect = 1;
    Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    Player2 = GameObject.Find("Player2");

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);


    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * topSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
    if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
        flip();
    else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
        flip();


}

void Update()
{
    if(grounded&& Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
    }
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (characterselect==1)
            {
                characterselect = 2;
            }
            else if (characterselect==2)
            {
                characterselect = 1;
            }
        }
        if (characterselect==1)
        {
            Player.SetActive(true);
            Player2.SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (characterselect==2)
        {
            Player.SetActive(false);
            Player2.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

}

void flip()
{
    facingRight = ! facingRight;

    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

    theScale.x *= -1;

    transform.localScale = theScale;


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a controller is a good start for this, but you got to think about how you different you want your characters to be. If they're going to be completely different, then think about a creating a "PlayerCharacter" interface that has functions for all possible commands for example

```
public interface IPlayerCharacter
{
    void DoActionA();
    void DoActionB();
}
```

If you do not know what an interface is, it's basically a empty class that defines functions, but not yet creates code for them. Because of this you can very easily implement very different players. Because you can call the functions from an instance of this interface.

Then, add this component to your controller, and if you now switch from Player 1 to Player 2 It should probably be a bit like this

```
public class PlayerController_Jumper : MonoBehaviour, IPlayerCharacter 
{
    // Does a jump
    void DoActionA() 
    {
        rigidbody.AddVelocity(Vector3.Up, 100.0f);
    }
}
```

Something that has to be done with Interfaces is that you HAVE to define all pre-defined functions, so it'll probably complain about this code because there's no DoActionB(). But lets disregard that for now.

Then Add to your controller something like "IPlayerController Jumper" and any other cool characters you're planning to make!

Comment: The only main difference I want is the colliders, as it's going to be a simple game, each different character is a different shape

Comment: Oh, I see. You could simply use two different prefabs then, just make one of the colliders in the shape of the object with either a CircleCollider2D, PolygonCollider or a simple box collider.